# Visual Studio 2019 - Cannot run Python unittests - Failed to import test module:

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing

Was successfully developing on Python with VS2019 for last several days now. So my environment seems to be properly installed and appropriate configured.

---

So I want to use unittest for Python with Visual Studio 2019 and came along here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/unit-testing-python-in-visual-studio

Then started with a freshly created empty project.
The test module 'test_A.py' is located in a subfolder called "tests":

[image: Solution Explorer]

It is exactly the same code from the MS Docs example (Link above):

```
    import unittest

    class Test_test1(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_A(self):
            self.fail("Not implemented")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

In the project settings I turned on 'unittest' and set the root folder like this:

[image: Project Settings]

The Test Explorer is directly showing the test class:

[image: Test Explorer]

But running the tests, always this ImportError comes up, that the module cannot be found and therefore is not existing:

```
Test Name:  test_A
Test FullName:  test_A::tests\test_A.py::Test_test1::test_A
Test Source:    D:\pyproject\pyproject\tests\test_A.py : line 4
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Test Name:  test_A
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StackTrace:  3.7
Result Message: Failed to import test module: test_A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_A'
Result StandardError:   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\unittest\case.py", line 628, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_A'
```

Why is Visual Studio in trouble, when previously detecting the test module??? Somewhat strange to me...
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issues with `pytest` in different IDEs and the solution was to add `__init__.py` in the `tests` folder. You can try that.

Comment: Simple, but uncommented on the MS Doc Page... THX, mate. It works!! :)))

Comment: @SiL3NC3, great! And yeah, I also was shocked that this solved my issue back then xD

Comment: This should definitely be added to the MS Docs!